# Scroll with easing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to animate one sigle-paged-website and when I click on the menu it scrolls to that section, I added a simple animation with a constant speed but I want something like this when you click on the menu >>> http://www.sergioarantes.com/ 
I found that easing jquery could help and here is my js code "it's not working"

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#first-showup header nav .nav-bar #menu-items ul li a").click(function(){

var $block = $(this).data("block");

var $thisBlock = $("#"+$block);


  $("html, body").animate({
    "scrollTop": $thisBlock.position().top }, 
          {
              duration: 1200,
              easing: "easeInOutExpo"
          });
  });
```

On their website on this animation they say to use this model:

```
div.animate({ top: '-=100px' }, 600, 'easeInQuart', function () { … })
```

But I can't modify it on my code
thank you

Richard.

Comment: Do you have a `jsfiddle` or something to show more of what's going on with your code?

Comment: here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/6ta43p1z/

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#first-showup header nav .nav-bar #menu-items ul li a").click(function(){

        var $block = $(this).data("block");

        var $thisBlock = $("#"+$block);

             $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $thisBlock.offset().top
            }, 1000);

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery method `$(selector).animate();` requires as first parameter a `Object` containing some CSS properties camelCase written. The property `scrollTop` is not a CSS property. In any case you can solve the problem in some ways, like:

- Create a Javascript/jQuery function that sets `scrollTop` property on the document, you can do it basically with a simple `window.setInterval();`
- Use a CSS Trick (look [Scroll Based Animations jQuery CSS3](https://www.sitepoint.com/scroll-based-animations-jquery-css3/)) to make scrolling effect on the page and animate it.

Good luck!